# Number of (cube map) texture samplers on iOS hardware

Tags: ios, iphone, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

Is there a list of iOS hardware (current and past) with the number of available texture samplers in an OpenGL ES 2.0 application? I am particularly interested in the number of cube map samplers (is there a difference?).

I know that I can determine it at runtime, but I do not have every single device on hand.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Buy all the devices!]

No, really, there's the [OpenGL ES chapter in Apple's *iOS Device Compatibility Reference*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/OpenGLESPlatforms/OpenGLESPlatforms.html).

It lists most of the interesting capability limits for devices supported by the last few major versions of iOS, including the number of texture units (`MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS`, `MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS`, or `MAX_VERTEX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS` depending on how you want to use them). Note that this number can change depending on the API version of the `EAGLContext` you're using.

A cube map uses a single texture unit, and a texture unit corresponds to a GLSL `sampler2D` or `samplerCube`, so the number of units is the number of samplers.

Use the [*Device Compatibility Reference*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/OpenGLESPlatforms/OpenGLESPlatforms.html) to aid in planning your renderer design, but never hardcode assumptions about specific devices in your app -- otherwise you'll be haunted by the Ghost of iOS Devices Future. If you need to vary your app's behavior based on device capabilities, you should still test those capabilities at run time.

Comment: Thanks! 8 is more than I will need.